# Use jQuery to get text of target

Tags: jquery, events, target

Trying to get the text of an event's target element from an unordered list

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

with code like this

```
$('ul').click(function() {
theEl=(event.target.text);
});
```

When I console log

```
event.target
```

it returns

```
 <li>Item 1</li>
```

and

event.target.text

returns undefined

I just want 'Item 1'. I know I have done this before - it must be late...thanks for any assistance :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use jQuery's text function:

```
$(event.target).text()
```

Answer (score 10):

You're confusing raw JS and jQuery.

In jQuery, you'd use `$(event.target).text()`

However, it's much more efficient in JavaScript: `event.target.firstChild.nodeValue`

EDIT: Here's a [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/js-text-jquery) as proof.

Comment: Good JSPerf - way faster in JS! Marked Jeff's as correct answer b/c he was first to answer, but thanks for the detail.

Answer (score 2):

The reason `event.target.text` is undefined is because HTMLElement does not have that method or property defined. However, jQuery does have `text()` which is what you were looking for. In order to access jQuery methods or properties, you need to wrap the current HTMLElement in a jquery object. This is done by passing it to jQuery, who then creates a function object with it, and the jQuery prototype which exposes the API.

```
jQuery(element);//in general
$(event.target).text();//for your situation
```

Answer (score 2):

```
event.target.textContent
```

It is javascript access too. I recommend to you execute 'Chrome' (or Firefox) javascript console with `Ctrl+Shift+J`. Write in your code: `console.log(event)` and watch the out on console. You can watch every attribute of object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -> event.target.innerText

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Vanilla JS:

```js
event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].text
```