# How to get value from React Select Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

Sorry for just a basic question, But I'm a little stuck here to find any way to get values from React Select after making a selection.

This is a Simple Selection setup.

```
    const selectOptions = [
            { value: 'YES', label: 'Set to Active' },
            { value: 'NO', label: 'Set to Mute' }
       ]

    <Label className='form-label'>Select</Label>
         <Select
            isClearable={false}
            className='react-select'
            classNamePrefix='select'
            options={selectOptions}
            theme={selectThemeColors}
          />
```

I want to get the value against user-selected choice and put it into `userChoice` content using `useState`.

```
const [userChoice, setUserChoice] = useState("")
```

value can be YES or NO as defined in selectOptions. But how to pass this into userChoice.
I tried using `onChange={(e) => setUserChoice(e.target.value)}`  But this thing is not working.

Also tried `onInputChange={handleInputChange}` as suggested in previously asked threads on StackOverflow but not working here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use jQuery to get text of target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720807/use-jquery-to-get-text-of-target)

Comment: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/react+select+onchange

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `onChange` callback handler gets called with the whole choice object instead of the `event` object. Therefore it should be like this.

```
 <Select
      ...
      ...
      onChange={(choice) => setUserChoice(choice)}
 />
```

If you only intested in YES / NO value, then use,

```
onChange={(choice) => setUserChoice(choice.value)}
```

[image: Edit exciting-bouman-gu4yj]

Comment: @Faisal Nazik, check this out !!

Comment: Yes this is returning data in this format {value: 'YES', label: 'Set to Active'}
label: "Set to Active"
value: "YES"
[[Prototype]]: Object

Answer (score 0):

if you want the id or int value instead of the text make sure you set the value to the id and the text to the string value. if you are using forms directly you can can it directly by e.target.value

```
<select id="branch" className="form-control" name='branch' } >
 {branch.map(e => (<option key={e.id}  value={e.id}   selected= >{e.branch}</option>))}   
                                </select>
```

then call it directly in a function

```
const UpdateSubmit (e)=>{
        alert(e.target.branch.value)
........
}
```

if you dont do so you will get only String value